# How to use the id of the first INSERT in another INSERT query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a couple of tables that are joined:
Table A ([Id], [Name], [Active])
Table B ([Id], [Name], [A_Id])

I would like to insert into Table A first, then use the Id of the new row to insert into Table B.

```
DECLARE @NEWID table(NewID Numeric(19, 0));

INSERT [dbo].[TableA] ([Name], [Active]) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @NEWID (NewID)
VALUES ('testtesttest', 1);

INSERT [dbo].[TableB] ([Name], [A_Id])
VALUES ('name for b', ??? @NEWID.NewID ???)
```

I can OUTPUT the id into a temporary table but how do I use this in the next insert statement?

Comment: the linking column should be A_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you're running into is that the target of the OUTPUT clause needs to be a table-like thing (in this case, you're using a table variable which works), but the values clause needs a scalar. So you'll need to introduce a scalar variable into the mix.

```sql
DECLARE @NEWID table(NewID Numeric(19, 0));
DECLARE @NEWIDValue Numeric(19, 0);

INSERT [dbo].[TableA] ([Name], [Active]) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @NEWID (NewID)
VALUES ('testtesttest', 1);

set @NEWIDValue = (select NewID from @NEWID);

INSERT [dbo].[TableB] ([Name], [B_Id])
VALUES ('name for b',@NEWIDValue);
```

Alternatively, and fancier (read may or may not work based on your use case) is to use the OUTPUT clause from the first insert to insert into the second table directly

```sql
INSERT [dbo].[TableA] ([Name], [Active]) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id, 'name for b' INTO [dbo].[TableB] ([B_Id], [Name])
VALUES ('testtesttest', 1);
```

Yet another approach is to use the table variable as the source in an `insert into... select` statement. Like so:

```sql
DECLARE @NEWID table(NewID Numeric(19, 0));

INSERT [dbo].[TableA] ([Name], [Active]) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @NEWID (NewID)
VALUES ('testtesttest', 1);

INSERT [dbo].[TableB] ([Name], [B_Id])
SELECT 'name for b', NewID
FROM @NEWID;
```

Comment: Thank you. Works likes a charm!

Answer (score 1):

the user defined variable is @NEWID, which isn ba table and that gets filled
so use it as you wpould use any other table, where you need to get onoly one Value

```
CREATE TABLE tableA  
(  
 ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
   [Name] varchar (200), [Active] int
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE tableB  
(  
 ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
   [Name] varchar (200), [A_ID] int
);
```

```
    DECLARE @NEWID table(NewID BIGINT);
    
    INSERT [dbo].[TableA] ([Name], [Active]) 
    OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @NEWID (NewID)
    VALUES ('testtesttest', 1);
    
    INSERT [dbo].[TableB] ([Name], [A_Id])
    VALUES ('name for b', (SELECT TOP 1 NewID FROM @NEWID ORDER BY NewID DESC))
```

```
2 rows affected
```

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
```

| ID | Name | Active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | testtesttest | 1 |

```
SELECT * FROM tableB
```

| ID | Name | A_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name for b | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mbGopwbr)

Comment: tried that, I get a 'Must declare the scalar variable' on MSSQL server

Comment: @user1094553 i updated my answer, with an example fiddle

Comment: Thank you. I realised the NewID is a table but wasn't sure how I would grab that value in SQL... Didn't know you could just use an inline SELECT like that